# sql server update table

Tags: sql-server

the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserName]  NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Pasword]   NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Name]      TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [LastName]  TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [Location]  TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [profesion] TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [Email]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Gender]    TEXT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserName] ASC)
);
```

i want to update to:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserName]  NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Pasword]   NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Name]      TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [LastName]  TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [Location]  TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [profesion] TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [Email]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Gender]    TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [moneyinmillions] INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserName] ASC)
);
```

the problem:

> an error occurred while the batch was being executed

thanks for the help

Comment: why this question has the `c#` tag?

Comment: I'm always surprised when people say they get an error and decide not to post the error message, and neither the code they used. Anyway, seems like you need to google "ALTER TABLE"

Comment: If you want to add columns to a table, why are you using a `CREATE TABLE` statement? You want `ALTER TABLE` and `ADD COLUMN`, etc. Also, can you post the actual error message?

Comment: @Sylverac not `UPDATE TABLE`, s/he needs `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: @Lamak Yep, brain fart. Corrected.

Comment: Could just google "How to add a column to an existing table in SQL Server"

Comment: As mentioned `ALTER` is what you're looking for, now you are just trying to recreate the table

Comment: Rather shocked that nobody mentioned two MAJOR problems in your design here. First is you are using the TEXT datatype. It has been deprecated since 2005 in favor of varchar(max). However, none of the columns you have require anywhere near that much data. varchar can hold up to 8,000 characters which is WAY more than you need. The second concern is you seem to be storing passwords in plain text. This is a major no no. You should be storing them after they have been salted and hashed.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of answering your question, here is the code you would want to add the `moneyinmillions` column to the `User` table:

```
ALTER TABLE [User]
ADD [moneyinmillions] INT NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ways to **Insert** a column in your existing `Table`

- Use the `ALTER TABLE` Statement

*Do the following:*

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]
ADD [moneyinmillions] INT NOT NULL
```

- Using the ***Table Designer***

  1. In **Object Explorer**, right-click the table *(here, `User` table)* to which you want to add columns and choose **Design**.
  2. Click in the first blank cell in the **moneyinmillions** column.
  3. Press the TAB key to go to the Data Type cell and select a **Data Type** from the dropdown.
  4. When you are finished adding columns, from the **File** menu, choose **Save** table name *(`User`)*.
- Using **DROP TABLE** and Re-Creating the Table

  `DROP TABLE [dbo].[User]`

and then **Execute** the statements below:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserName]  NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Pasword]   NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Name]      TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [LastName]  TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [Location]  TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [profesion] TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [Email]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Gender]    TEXT           NOT NULL,
    [moneyinmillions] INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserName] ASC));
```

*(**Note**: The **DROP Table** Statement will remove the table definition and all the data, indexes, triggers, constraints, and permission specifications for that table. So, if you have data entry in some fields/columns, then do not use the **DROP TABLE** Statement because you'll loose all the data).*

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that you can right click on the table and open the design view to add/remove columns to or from a table ??